# Можно ли обратиться к SATA SSD из операционной системы не поддерживающей trim и произвести запись напрямую обратившить к оборудованию?

Tags: c++, windows, ssd, trim

Изучаю вопрос прямого обращения к SSD с целью произведения записи с поддержкой trim на операционных системах не поддерживающих trim(Windows 98, Me, 2000).
То есть можно ли написать программный код например на C++ который будет производить запись файлов на SSD напрямую через обращение к оборудованию минуя API операционной системы?

Comment: Можно, но данный код должен работать не как пользовательское приложение, а как драйвер загруженный в ядро ОС

Comment: То есть операционная система никак не даст иначе это сделать? Может быть например может быть можно как то отключить устройство в ОС, чтобы оно не было доступно как диск, при этом определялось в диспетчере задач, после чего работать с ним напрямую?

Comment: Одна из задач ОС — это как раз ограничивать доступ пользовательского кода к железу. В Win95 точно (возможно и в 98) можно скомпилировать свой код в dos-совместимый com-файл и загрузить как драйвер просто указав его в autoexec.bat

Comment: Может быть знаете, если существуют аппаратные устройства для эмуляции trim для старых систем. Имею ввиду устройства которые к sata подключаются а уже к ним SSD. То есть ОС посылает запросы к устройству как к обычному диску, а устройство преобразует запрос и корректно работает с SSD?

Comment: Для "корректной работы" trim совершенно не нужен

Comment: Понятно что в теории если в ОС есть драйвер то не нужен, я имел ввиду может быть тем не менее есть такие устройства.

Comment: Выполнить trim на устройстве целиком много ума не надо, но вы-то скорее всего хотите, чтобы trim выполнялся только на незанятых блоках диска. Сведения о том, какие блоки заняты файлами, а какие свободны, есть только у файловой системы — то есть это неизбежно подразумевает какое-то взаимодействие с ОС

Comment: Похоже, что вам нужен NAS